# RN App crash at launch on testflight review eventhough it works on release mode simulator

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, testflight

Hello wonderful community

I'm trying to upload my app to testflight but it keeps beeing rejected. When i try it on all types of simulator in release mode it works...

Here are a lot of informations but feel free to ask for more if needed. I hope there is a hero out-here to help a poor lad

Here is my stack :

- "react": "17.0.1"
- "react-native": "0.64.0"
- Xcode 12.5
- IOS v14.5

Here is the crash log i get :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  7

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

Here is the Thread 7 crashing:

```
Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b666d334 0x1b6644000 + 168756
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d3b0daa0 0x1d3b0b000 + 10912
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019208fb90 0x192018000 + 490384
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d86fbb8 0x19d85c000 + 80824
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d860ec8 0x19d85c000 + 20168
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019d76d05c 0x19d766000 + 28764
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d86efa0 0x19d85c000 + 77728
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019d86ef2c 0x19d85c000 + 77612
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001888fc800 0x1888f8000 + 18432
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000188903fd4 0x1888f8000 + 49108
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000188904bd0 0x1888f8000 + 52176
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018890f48c 0x1888f8000 + 95372
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d3b0e7a4 0x1d3b0b000 + 14244
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d3b1574c 0x1d3b0b000 + 42828
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.12.13",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.6.20",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.16.4",
    "@firebase/auth-types": "^0.10.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^11.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "github:react-native-mapbox-gl/maps#master",
    "@react-native-segmented-control/segmented-control": "^2.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@turf/helpers": "^6.3.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "geolib": "^3.3.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "^4.0.2",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "pod-install": "^0.1.20",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-background-fetch": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.11.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^3.2.10",
    "react-native-formik": "^1.7.8",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-redux": "^1.0.10",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-modules": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-scale-bar": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-uuid-generator": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-persist-filesystem-storage": "^3.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "string-hash-64": "^1.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
```

At first i thought it was from fbsdk login so i stripped away the lib, did'nt work. I also tried to remove/update dependencies, did'nt work aswell.
When i check the symbolicated crash log it seems to come from RTCNativeModule.mm or some stuff quite cryptic i don't quite understand ...

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: You have a huge list of dependencies in your app which makes me thing the app is quite complex. In this case you should definitely test your app on a real device. Basically this should be done with any app as in a simulator many things work differently.

Comment: I have heard cases like this when something will work on the emulator and fail on a real device. I noticed some errors are displayed on the console, but since it works on the emulator it should work on actual devices, but it doesn't.

When testing using an emulator. look at the logs for any red texts. Then trace it to the function that might be prompting the red texts on the console. Try to fix, once you don't have the red texts on the console, you are good to go.

Comment: @Christian Thank you for your reply, it is indeed a complex project. I was/am hopping there is a way around because i don't quite want to buy an iphone but i guess in the end this is what i'll have to do ...

Comment: @IkelieCyril I actually don't have error logs in consol when running my app ^^

Comment: if you run your app with Xcode it will show you logs that are not shown in the console. These are the native logs.

Comment: This is already something i can work toward, maybe there are some errors i can fix, thank you